# How to convert a byte array (of a PBE-Key) back to a SecretKey?

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

***I need just clarification***, I'm currently working on a Java cryptotool using BouncyCastle.
Now I got the conversion working for every key I import back into my programm. But for keys using: "PBEWithSHA256And128BitAES-CBC-BC", I can't just import them back again.
To my **question**, do I really need to save the password, salt and iteration count for the reconstruction of the key? (my approach then would be that I put them in a new PBEKeySpec and use the SecretKeyFactory). Is there a better approach or is this the only one?

I already tried:
`SecretKey finalKey = new SecretKeySpec(Hex.decode(key), "PBEWithSHA256And128BitAES-CBC-BC");`
But an exception occurred.

Comment: The common reason to use a PBE cipher is that you don't want to store the key (nor the password). You only want ho save non-critical data like salt and iteration count and then use the password supplied by the user. This way a PBE cipher is used normally.

Comment: It's not clear to me what `key` is supposed to be in your code. Possibly the hex encoded value of `SecretKeySpec#getEncoded()`. However, for *PBEWithSHA256And128BitAES-CBC-BC*, which follows PKCS#12, this only returns the password (which is encoded according to [PKCS#12](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7292#appendix-B.1), i.e. with NULL terminator and UCS-2 BE encoding). The *actual* key and IV are only derived from this (for which the salt and the other parameters are mandatory). If necessary for any reason, you can determine key and IV (e.g. with BouncyCastle) and use them directly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!